# CSS last-child selector ... the last of the parent - not the last of the last

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

Hey I'm going crazy on this just can't find a solution

```
<div class="example">
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div> <-- Want to select this
        <div></div> <-- but it always selects this
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the last div of .example but it always selects the last div in the last div of .example if I do .example:last-child ...... How to do it right?

Comment: `.example > div:last-of-type{}`

Comment: `.example:last-child` does select the div you want. But certain things will be inherited by the inner div, such as color etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'div.example>div:last-child'`:

```js
alert(document.getElementById('forCompare') === document.querySelector('div.example>div:last-child'));
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="forCompare">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```